# How to detect Full screen gestures in Android 10

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-homebutton

I want to know is it possible to detect full screen gestures that introduced in Android 9. I tried BroadcastReceiver, it can detect traditional Home key and Task key press action. But it can't detect "swipe for Home key" action and "hold and swipe for Task key" action. Im wondering what are those two gesture's keyword, like Homekey's keyword  `final String SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_HOME_KEY = "homekey"`  . Any documents or links will be very helpful, thanks!